# Expected output is not sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Expected Output:

```
{'Albert': ['btech.txt', 'Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stanley': ['Code.py']}
```

```
from collections import defaultdict

def groupAndSortOwners(files):
    owners = defaultdict(list)
    for file, owner in files.items():
        owners[owner].append(file)
    return owners

files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Albert',
    'Code.py': 'Stanley',
    'Output.txt': 'Albert',
    'btech.txt':'Albert',
}

print(groupAndSortOwners(files))
```

Getting output as:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Albert': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt', 'btech.txt'],
                             'Stanley': ['Code.py']})
```

Please help me with the appropriate "sort statement" to get output as above.

Comment: want the dictionary elements sorted

Comment: If you simply want the list to be sorted aphalbatically you use `sorted()` https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sort-a-list-alphabetically-in-python

Comment: Change the last line to `return {k: sorted(v) for k, v in sorted(owners.items())}`?

Comment: Still not working 
I want btech.txt in beginning

Comment: current output: {'Albert': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt', 'btech.txt'], 'Stanley': ['Code.py']}
Expected output: {'Albert': ['btech.txt', 'Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}

Comment: Add `key=str.lower` to the `sorted` calls to make the sort case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
I've realised you want each array in alphabetical order. To solve this you can just iterate through each key on the object and just use the `sort` method to sort each array.

You can just add a new line which sorts the array after each operation:

```
owners[owner] = sorted(owners[owner], key=str)
```

The full code now is:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def groupAndSortOwners(files):
    owners = defaultdict(list)
    for file, owner in files.items():
        owners[owner].append(file)
        owners[owner] = sorted(owners[owner], key=str)

    return dict(owners)


files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Albert',
    'Code.py': 'Stanley',
    'Output.txt': 'Albert',
    'btech.txt':'Albert',
}

print(groupAndSortOwners(files))
```

**OLDER ANSWER**

The object returned is of type `defaultdict`. You need to change the `defaultdict` back to a standard `dict`. When returning the `owners`, cast the object to a `dict`. For example:

```
return dict(owners)
```

So the whole code now reads:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def groupAndSortOwners(files):
    owners = defaultdict(list)
    for file, owner in files.items():
        owners[owner].append(file)
    return dict(owners)


files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Albert',
    'Code.py': 'Stanley',
    'Output.txt': 'Albert',
    'btech.txt':'Albert',
}

print(groupAndSortOwners(files))
```

Comment: This isn't answering the question asked — which was about the sorting of the values in the resulting dictionary.

Comment: I am really unsure about your question. I have ran this code on my local machine with Python3 and it gave me the expected output. Please can you specify what you mean by 'not sorted'.

Comment: After reading the question again, do you mean that the output isn't sorted into alphabetical order?

Comment: See the very first line of the OP's question, it shows the order they want — I missed that too, at first. Most folks put it near the end of their questions.

Comment: @martineau Ive updated my response to fit the question better.

Comment: Your update isn't really much of an improvement — it's wrong in the sense the it should be `key=str.lower` not `key=str` in the `sorted()` call, plus suggesting that they resort on every addition is very inefficient since it only needs to be done *once* at the very end via `return {k: sorted(v, key=str.lower) for k, v in sorted(owners.items())}`. Also note that I am not the person who downvoted your original answer — although I tempted to, now…